# Charset UTF-8, Can't solve it

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Swedish website where the content is containing `ÅÄÖ` and I had a problem with inserting those into the mysql table, I fixed it using `"alter table tablename convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci"`. That is working properly but when I set the http charset encoding to UTF-8 then the special characters from the table get this symbol "�".
When I remove the http charset the html special characters get weird but not the characters from the table.

I know there are quite many other questions like this on Stackoverflow, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: the file encoding should be utf8 too

Comment: Ok, that may work, I will check it up!

Comment: And yo also have to check the encoding your database client is set to. Also note that you might have to manually convert content already stored inside the table when you change the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixing this by setting the DB connection also to the correct charset.

mysql_set_charset("UTF8");

Answer (score 0):

You have to also set the character set of the MySQL connection, so that MySQL returns the results encoded with UTF-8.

Setting the character set for the connection can be done with your MySQL connection setup. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php on how to do it.